# How to get ConnectionString from Secrets.json in Asp.Net Core 6?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, connection-string, secretsmanager

I am new to Asp.Net Core and EF. I am developing a simple CRUD from database-end, using the `Secrets.json` file to hide my connection string credentials.

But I don't know how to reference the file using AddDbContext().

My code so far:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<POTS.myDBContext>(options => 
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConxStr")));
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

When the code runs, I get this error on the `AddDbContext<>` line

> System.ArgumentNullException   HResult=0x80004003   Message=Value
> cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer   StackTrace: etc etc

I think this is because the code is looking for the parameter in the `appsettings.json` file, where **I don't want** the connectionstring to be.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it is ASP.NET Core 6 not 5? You use Startup.cs in your project.

Comment: @Rena based off tutorials, I added setup.cs manually myself. I know it's not needed. Still learning.

Comment: Hi @Fandango68, Got it. Any way, two situaction I have shared below. You could check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Before ASP.NET 6**:

You can  adding additional `Secrets.json` file to configuration argument in `Startup.cs` like below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("Secrets.json")
        .Build();

        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    //...
}
```

Or add it in Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

        config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("Secrets.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

**In ASP.NET 6**:

You can add it in `Program.cs` like below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("Secrets.json");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<POTS.myDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConxStr")));

// Add services to the container....
var app = builder.Build();
//....
```

Then be sure your **json file**(`Secrets.json`) **must be like below**:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myConxStr": "xxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually didn't need to do anything other than your last suggestion to place the word "ConnectionString" in the secrets.json file. So yeah that alone worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Rena, I came back to this again because when deploying to IIS, it's not working. I don't get any data showing.

Comment: Since I am using EF, I've read that the SQL Server dataabase login has to have Admin access and be able to create tables, because EF tries to create a resource table in relation to connecting to it. Weird I know. I am trying to deploy using a read-only SQL login, as I am not writing back to the database.

Comment: Also, the above by directly referencing secrets.json failed as it's a Connected Services resource. There is no actual secrets.json file in the project's root folder. That would defeat the purpose of hiding the connection string.

Answer (score 3):

In the MS documentation there is a full walk through for [app secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows). Of note, even MS suggests this is for non-production use. If you need Startup.cs, the top left there is a dropdown to select v5 or earlier.

**Basic Steps for ASP.NET Core 6.0 (refer to link above):**

1. Initialize the secrets within the project directory via cli, a 'UserSecretsId' will be created in the PropertyGroup in the projectName.csproj file:

   dotnet user-secrets init
2. Create the new secret:

   dotnet user-secrets set "MyDbPassword" "SuperSecretPassword123"
3. A secrets.json file is created:

   - Windows: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets<user_secrets_id>\secrets.json
   - Mac/Linux: ~/.microsoft/usersecrets/<user_secrets_id>/secrets.json

To use in Program.cs in your case for the ConnectionStrings, scroll down in the documentation to 'String replacement with secrets'

```
var conStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnectionWithoutPassword"));
conStrBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["MyDbPassword"];
var connection = conStrBuilder.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Thank you. So I *can* use secrets in a production deployment? I thought it was purely for development only

Comment: No, this is for non-production use. I have an internal only app and it works for that ;) MS suggests Azure Key Vault (of course)